# Как обрабатывать запросы к nginx через Python

Tags: python, nginx

Сразу скажу что в веб программирования полный ноль, я недавно ток поднял nginx. И вот стала задача надо при запросе к определенному URI делалось какое либо действие(скрипт на питоне) на сервере или вообще на соседнем

Comment: Запускаете веб-сервер с вашим скриптом на питоне и перенаправляете на него запросы из nginx опцией proxy_pass

Comment: Или поднимаете CGI-сервер (например fcgiwrap), кладёте скрипт в папочку cgi-bin и направляете на него запросы из nginx опцией fastcgi_pass

Comment: Окей сейчас попробую

Comment: @andreymal, ваши два комментария вполне являются ответом на вопрос. больше подробностей и не требуется (их можно привести в ответе на более детальный вопрос).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin можете написать ответ если хотите